# How to prepare window stool for tiling in shower

Tags: bathroom, windows, tile

Vinyl windows were retrofitted over existing tile. Removed what concrete and tile I could from inside shower which of course chipped into some of the tile and concrete between the window and frame. What is the best way to prep this area to create a smooth surface prior to installing barrier and backer board?

[image: Window]

Answer (score 2):

As far as getting the existing material any farther back, don't sweat it. The part that will need the attention is the vinyl face of the window frame. Build up the framing with a 5-10 degree slope to the inside of the shower on the bottom  and square with the other 3 sides. Set them so the framing is even with the edge of the window frame. then add the cement backer. Tape all the joints with fiberglass tape and modified thinset, keep it neat. After it has set for a day, paint it all with liquid applied membrane like Redgard(r) or similar. make a nice line onto the face of the window, high enough to seal, but low enough for the tile to conceal the membrane, let it cure, then set your tile.

Comment: The slope is important and do just as @jack suggest and it will look good and last.+